# Where is Mega.nz downloading files to using Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, download, location

I am using Chrome to download folders full of files. The downloads complete but my PC does not have AppData directory in the User folder so the below path is obviously incorrect. The files are also NOT in the downloads directory even though Chrome is set to direct all downloads there.

> C: \ Users \ [UserName] \ AppData \ Local \ Google \ Chrome \ User Data \ Default \ File System in the folder 011 ... 015

I have searched Google for any reference to where Mega.nz drops files using Chrome and my PC has none of the directories listed in any responces.

Comment: What is the name and version of the operative system that you are using?

Comment: “my PC does not have a AppData directory” - Impossible AppData is a required directory for Windows to function

Comment: The MEGA web client (available on GitHub) uses your browser's regular download mechanism—once downloading and decryption is finished.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you are using MegaSync or just Chrome alone, then it's defined in Chrome's prefs, or MegaSync's.

If undefined, it will be your regular user Downloads folder C:/Users/[user]/Downloads, accessible from these 3 marked locations.

[image]

Windows never expects regular users to need to dig inside AppData.

Answer (score 0):

From [Download a file](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95759?hl=en)

> If you didn't change your default download location, then Google Chrome downloads files to the following locations:
>
> - Windows 10 and up: \Users<username>\Downloads
> - Mac: /Users//Downloads
> - Linux: /home//Downloads